# When Bayesian and frequentist hypothesis testing leads to same results?

Tags: bayesian, statistical-significance, frequentist

Under what conditions do the Bayesian and frequentist hypothesis testing lead to the same conclusion (rejection or acceptance of a hypothesis)? For example, if the test concerns statistical independence between two categorical variables?

Comment: In large samples they will agree approximately and this will also be the case if the prior is uninformative regarding the null hypothesis.

Comment: So, if I have no prior beliefs, I can use either one and end up with the same result?

Comment: If you have no prior belief why bother with the Bayesian approach?

Comment: That was exactly the point! I have just begun to study the Bayesian approach and the papers always advertise how much better it is. I wanted to check if a non-believer would ever benefit from the Bayesian approach in hypothesis testing. I understood the situation is different in parameter estimation.